# wireshark capture the traffic of other devises in LAN

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

I am using wireshark on windows to capture my traffic.

Is there a way to capture the traffic of other computers which are connected to the same LAN.
If it is not possible with wireshark, is there other tool capable of doing this.

Comment: There is a wireshark tag for several reasons. Namely, WireShark is open source, which would lead me to believe that people have development questions related to it, but also because people ask questions that don't belong here. This question should be moved to probably either serverfault or superuser.

Comment: Check the FAQ before getting a sour attitude, as I'm trying to help you. Being rude just makes you look like a fool. http://stackoverflow.com/faq , This is not my belief, these are the guidelines of SO. This question belongs on Serverfault, http://serverfault.com/faq .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are connected to the other computers by a network hub, then you will be able to see the other computers' traffic. However, if you are connected through a network switch (which is more likely), then you will not be able to see any of their traffic.

There may be other more intrusive tools to use, possibly some that use arp-spoofing, but I would not recommend this unless you are on your **own private network** and know what you are doing.